# foreach loop not working for simplexmlelement in php

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I m accessing an api and reading the content with Simplexml element.But when i m using foreach loop for accessing the values for nodes.It gives me value for only first loop.not for others....
below is my code

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
header("Content-Type: text/xml;");
function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'header1:value1',
    'header2:value2'
    )); 
    $output=curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
$data= httpGet("http://apiurl");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->node1->node2->node3 as $info) {
   echo $info->name, ' played by ', $info->actor, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

xml format which i m reading

```
    <?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
    <main>
     <node1>
      <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
      <node2>
       <node3>
        <name>Ms. Coder</name>
        <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
       </node3>
</node2>
<node2>
       <node3>
        <name>Mr. Coder</name>
        <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
       </node3>
      </node2>
     </node1>
    </main>
```

When i m running above php code for reading api content which is having xml format as shown above.
I want to read name and actor node using foreach loop.but i m not able to access only first name and actor node under node3,not the second one....
Please correct the foreach loop or any flaw in code..Please highlight and help me in correcting that....

Comment: what happens when you foreach ($xml->node1->node2->node3 as $key = $value) {var_dump $key}

Comment: I m sorry i pasted incomplete xml format.now have corrected and completed that..Please validate once again

Answer (score 0):

maybe set it like this

```
foreach ($xml->node1->node2 as $info) {
   echo $info->node3->name, ' played by ', $info->node3->actor, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I m sorry i pasted incomplete xml format.now have corrected and completed that..Please validate once again.Really sorry for that....